# Undefined locus for rational map has codimension $\ge 2$, but vanishing locus has codimension 1?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, complex-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $X$ be smooth surface, such that $f:X\dashrightarrow \Bbb{A}^1\subset \Bbb{P}^1$ is a rational map, we have the standard result that the rational map into projective space has undetermined locus of codimension $\ge 2$.

However by definition over the undetermined point $p\in X$ there exist a $f_1,f_2 \in \mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ such that $f_2(p) = 0$ and $f_1/f_2 = f$ locally, since the vanishing locus of $f_2$ say $V(f_2)$ has codimension 1, does this means that undetermined locus is codimension 1.

I know there must be something wrong since the undetermined locus is codimension $\ge 2$, not 1.

Comment: Sorry I ask a siily question example $x_1/x_2$ over $\Bbb{A}^1$ has undetermined locus codimension 1, but for projective space, we add some "infinity", so there are more defined points, it reduced the codimension to $\ge 2$

Comment: that just like what we did in Riemann surface that meromorphic function is indeed holomorphic into Riemann sphere as the dimension drop 2 to (-1)

Comment: There's a related question from a number of years ago that might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215990/any-rational-map-can-be-extended-to-codimension-one